# Objective c: How to add strings from .txt file to NSArray?

Tags: objective-c

I have weekdays.txt file in my project. There are days of the week with spaces among them in this file. And my code is not working.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"weekdays" ofType:@"txt"];
weekdaysDataSource = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Where can be the problem? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What format is your file?

The documentation for `-initWithContentsOfFile` says `path` should be "The path to a file containing a string representation of an array produced by the writeToFile:atomically: method." That would be a property list.

If your file is not a property list, you could read the file into an NSString (`+[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:]`) and then split it into words (`-[NSArray componentsSeparatedByString:]`).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following:

```
// create an NSURL object that holds the path of the file you want to read

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/yourname/weekdays.txt"];  

//Create an NSMutaable string object and use the stringWithContentsOfURL: encoding: error: method to hold whatever might be you have in the text file. 
//Just pass the NSURL object you created in the previous step to as an argument like so

NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfURL:fileURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"The content of the file is: %@", text);
```

And that's it. The NSLog will actually output whatever you had typed inside the file just to prove this works.